# Input file is not getting the correct file on secound upload

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

## I have a problem with a input field to upload a image. When the user update there image / upload a file.

It works fine the first try, but if they want to change it again right after they updated it, some weird things happen.

First time uploading a image, it's the correct image that is uploaded.

Secound time, it will choose the first again. (I wan't the image that the user uploaded)

Third time it will put the correct image, as it was the first try.

What am i missing? Image name is also diffrent.

**.../ProfileImageChangeComponent.tsx**

```js
  function handleUpload(e: File | any) {
  const loaderToast = toast.loading("Uploader...");
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const fileExt = file?.name?.split(".").pop();
  const fileSize = file?.size;

console.log(e.target.files && e.target.files[0]);

if (file) {
  if (fileSize > 15000000) {
    toast.error("Billedet må ikke være større end 15MB!");
    toast.dismiss(loaderToast);
    return;
  }

  if (fileExt == "jpg" || fileExt == "png" || fileExt == "jpeg") {
    props.setprofilePicturePreview(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    props.setprofilePicture(file);
    toast.dismiss(loaderToast);
    toast.promise(
      CLIENT_API.put(
        "merchant/profile_picture/",
        {
          image: file,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      ).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.new);
        sessionStorage.setItem(
          "user",
          JSON.stringify({
            ...user,
            profile_picture: res.data.new,
          })
        );

        setUser({
          ...user,
          profile_picture: res.data.new,
        });
      }),
      {
        loading: "Opdatere din profil...",
        success: (data) => {
          props.fileUpload.current.value = "";
          e.target.files = null;

          sessionStorage.setItem(
            "user",
            JSON.stringify({
              ...user,
            })
          );

          return `Dit profilbillede er opdateret`;
        },
        error: (error) => {
          if (error?.response?.data?.detail) {
            return error?.response?.data?.detail;
          } else return error?.response?.data?.message;
        },
      },
      { error: { duration: 5000 } }
    );
  } else {
    toast.error(
      "Billedet skal være i jpg, png eller jpeg format!" + fileExt
    ),
      { duration: 5000 };
    toast.dismiss(loaderToast);
  }
} else {
  toast.dismiss(loaderToast);
}
  }


      <input
      type="file"
      ref={props.fileUpload}
      accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg"
      onChange={(e) => {
        handleUpload(e);
      }}
      hidden
    />
```